# Forest package not working at all

Tags: forest

I have used the `forest` package for several years and I hadn't had any problem until now. It simply stopped working. I use Texstudio, but I tried the same file with TeXShop and got the same error, so I thought the problem had do with the TeX installation. I reinstalled MacTeX, updated all the packages, but still no luck. Here's a MWE and the error I get.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [A [B] [C] ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.8.16)  16 AUG 2022 15:57
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Test.tex
(./Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-05>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (./forest.sty
Package: forest 2013/01/28 v1.03 Drawing (linguistic) trees

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen139
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen140
```

Lots of lines more, and (right before) the error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count293
\scratchdimen=\dimen196
\scratchbox=\box84
\nofMPsegments=\count294
\nofMParguments=\count295
\everyMPshowfont=\toks36
\MPscratchCnt=\count296
\MPscratchDim=\dimen197
\MPnumerator=\count297
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count298
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks37
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \locbox 
                   \forest@temp@box \forestolet {box}\forest@temp@box 
l.11 \end{forest}
```

I am using TeXstudio on macOS Monterey.

Comment: Is that the first error? `\locbox` originally cam from `etex.sty` but years ago (2015 or so) I wrote `elocalalloc` to define it for forest your log should show `(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elocalloc/elocalloc.sty
Package: elocalloc 2016/12/15 v0.03 local allocation for LaTeX 2015+ (DPC)`

Comment: Yes, that's the first error. The log file does not contain any line with ```elocalalloc ```. Do I have to install that package? (I already noticed it is installed...)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I use recent `article`  as well `forest` package.

Comment: I would guess you have a local ancient copy of forest in your path. the log for your test file should show `(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/forest/forest.sty
Package: forest 2017/07/14 v2.1.5 Drawing (linguistic) trees`  the full path should be same as path to `article.cls` etc

Comment: David, would you believe me if I tell you that line is not in the log? I am updating the error to show what the log looks like.

Comment: The line @DavidCarlisle is referring to is what *should* appear. What you're showing is `Package: forest 2013/01/28 v1.03 Drawing (linguistic) trees` which is very old. This is probably in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex` and you should remove it.

Comment: As I guessed above `(./forest.sty`  You have  copy of forest.sty in your local directory. delete it

Comment: I checked ```~/Library/texmf/tex/latex``` and the folder is empty...

Comment: Yes, as @DavidCarlisle points out it's actually in the same folder as your source document.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I had too many files in that folder. I guess it's time to organise my mess. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your log shows

`(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`

so your TeX is rooted at `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/`

so you will have `forest 2017/07/14 v2.1.5` installed at

`/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/forest/forest.sty`

However TeX is using

```
(./forest.sty
Package: forest 2013/01/28 v1.03 Drawing (linguistic) trees
```

That is, a truly ancient version *in the working directory*

Delete `./forest.sty` and then TeX will find the version installed with texlive 2022.